# How scientists can be confident that human embryo tail is really a tail?

Tags: evolution, embryology

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail):

> Human embryos have a tail that measures about one-sixth of the size of the embryo itself. As the embryo develops into a fetus, the tail is absorbed by the growing body.

How are we sure that it is a real tail and is not a superficial resemblance of something else?

I ask this because some creationist guy challenged me in this regard.

Comment: I just want to ask one thing: what else could it (tail-like thing) be, another hand or another leg?

Comment: It is an extension of the vertebrae. Isn't that a good reason?

Comment: @user40602 If you consider your question has been answered, you can check your favourite answer.

Answer (score 5):

We can be sure it's a tail because it is an extension of the vertebrae, and we define "tail" as an extension of the vertebrae, among other things.

> ## tail
>
> **tāl/**
>
> noun: tail; plural noun: tails
>
> 1. the hindmost part of an animal, especially when prolonged beyond the rest of the body, *such as the flexible extension of the backbone in a vertebrate*, the feathers at the hind end of a bird, or a terminal appendage in an insect.

Emphasis mine. Source: [www.oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tail)

Comment: Some mention of the identical embryology would make this better, the human tail is not just a tail because of its location. not all tails are the same.  the human tail is homologous with other vertebrate tails.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what would you call it? Have a look at the images below ([source](https://embryology.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php/Carnegie_Embryos)):

[image: carnegie collection embryos]

If you would call what other species have *tails*, then the human one should also be called so. After all, they are extremely similar (the last image, k, is human):

[image: Mammalian embryos]

> a Echidna or spiny anteater (Tachyglossus aculeatus).
>   Because of the extreme rarity of monotreme material we
>   were only able to obtain this embryo, which is younger than the
>   tailbud stage. b Brush-tailed possum (Trichosurus vulpecula). c
>   Eastern Australian native “cat” (Dasyurus quoll). d Domestic cat*
>   (Felis catus). e Domestic dog (Canis familiaris). f Domestic sheep
>   (Ovis aries). g Scaly anteater (Manis javanica). h Rat (Rattus norvegicus).
>   i Rabbit (Oryctolagus cuniculus). j Hedgehog (Erinaceus
>   europaeus). k Human (Homo sapiens).

The above image was taken from M.K. RIchardson *et. al.*,*Anat Embryol* (**1997**) **196**:91–106 (a PDF can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Glenda_Wright/publication/13942761_There_is_no_highly_conserved_embryonic_stage_in_the_vertebrates_implications_for_current_theories_of_evolution_and_development/links/54d386100cf2b0c6146da4b9.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

## FUN FACT

Let's start with a fun fact!

In some rare cases, humans can get born with a tail. These tails can then be removed by surgical procedure. Such procedure are quite simple and are a relatively old procedure (see [Speigelmann et al. 1985](http://thejns.org/doi/abs/10.3171/jns.1985.63.3.0461?journalCode=jns)).

## What is a tail?

> The tail is the section at the rear end of an animal's body [..]. It is the part of the body that corresponds roughly to the sacrum and coccyx in mammals, reptiles, and birds

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail)

[Sacrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacrum) and [Coccyx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coccyx) are the last parts of the vertebral column. A tail is therefore, just an extension of the vertebral column.

## How does it look like in humans?

[image]

[image]

## Is it really a tail that we see?

Yes! Human embryo have been dissected and histologic analyses were performed. There are no doubt, it is a tail!

See [Dao and Netski (1984)](http://www.humanpathol.com/article/S0046-8177(84)80079-9/abstract), [Belzberg et al. (1991)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002234689190343R) and [Fallon and Simandi (2005)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/aja.1001520108/abstract) for further description and evidence.